# jQuery extend ajax parameters

Tags: ajax, jquery, extend

Ohey,

I have a central function that runs AJAX requests throughout my order form. I have default settings (essentially ajaxSetup, but I didn't want to use that), and then each function passes in its own settings/parameters. * USING jQuery 1.6.1

Only issue is I'm using $.extend (neither deep extend nor normal works). It seems extending doesn't carry along some of the functions. The weird thing is this worked once but now it doesnt and I can't figure out why :|. The ajax request does run, but nothing happens on success... I call sendData in this instance with $.when(this.sendData(params, 'snapshotCache')).then(do stuff);

Here's my code:

```
    this.sendData = function(options, cacheIndex) {

  var defaults = {
    url: this.dataPath + options.action,
    data: 'qs=NULL',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text/html', //(THIS SHOULD HAVE BEEN just 'text')
    success: function(result, textStatus, xhr) {
      console.log(cacheIndex)
      console.log('HELLO')
      if(typeof cacheIndex !== 'undefined') {
        var qs = settings.data;
        cacheObj.cacheAdd(qs, cacheIndex, result);
        alert(cacheObj);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if(textStatus === 'timeout') {
         $.ajax(this); // retry
         return;
       } else if(errorThrown === 500) {
        alert(ERROR['500Msg']);
       }
    }
  };
  var settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
  return $.ajax(settings);
};
```

Here's what is in the object settings before I return:

```
url => /order/getsnapshot
data => micro=img%2Fstore%2Fcomp-08.png%2Cimg%2Fstore%2Fcomp-08n.png%2Cimg%2Fstore%2Fcomp-08t.png%2Cimg%2Fstore%2Fcomp-08a.png%2Cimg%2Fstore%2Fcomp-08l.png%2Cimg%2Fstore%2Fcomp-08h.png&outPath=1242353103103.png
type => POST
dataType => text/html
success => function (result, textStatus, xhr) { console.log(cacheIndex); console.log("HELLO"); if (typeof cacheIndex !== "undefined") { var qs = settings.data; alert(cacheObj); } }
error => function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { if (textStatus === "timeout") { $.ajax(this); return; } else if (errorThrown === 500) { alert(ERROR['500Msg']); } }
action => getsnapshot
cache => true
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Sorry, just added - jQuery 1.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `$.when()` is not needed. Below is sufficient:

```
this.sendData(params, 'snapshotCache')).done(function(){ ... });
```

Keep in mind with the new deferreds, `done()` is like success and `fail()` is like error.

Also, I would just do this for your settings objects:

```
var settings = {};
$.extend(true, settings, defaults, options);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that. I did that, but still, it's not running the success callback set in the defaults... even when I don't have a 'then'. Even when I move the defaults into the return $.ajax instead of extending, it still doesn't work...

Comment: are you sure its not trying to call the error callback instead? Are there any errors being thrown in your console?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I don't know why I had never logged in the ERROR function... its returning "parsererror
No conversion from text to text/html" OK... So thanks, I'm a complete moron. text/html is a MIME TYPE but not a jquery DATATYPE (its just 'text')... so that fifxed it M_M THANK YOU for putting me on the right track!